# How to find a best of 2 in 3 column and average of those 2

Tags: mysql, sql, average

In my database I have a table `analog` with columns like `id`, `name`, `IA1`, `IA2`, `IA3` and `average`.

In the `average` column I need to set the average of the highest two values in `IA1`, `IA2` and `IA3`.

For example:

- anil has 20, 15 and 28 in `IA1`, `IA2`, `IA3` respectively so `average` will be (20+28)/2 i.e. 24
- ashwin has 21, 30 and 28 in `IA1`, `IA2`, `IA3` respectively so `average` will be (30+28)/2  i.e. 29

I tried this query but I got only the greatest of those values:

```
update analog set average = greatest (IA1,IA2,IA3);
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have only three values, you can subtract the `LEAST` of the 3 from the sum of all of them and then divide that by 2 to get the average of the two largest values:

```
UPDATE analog
SET average = (IA1 + IA2 + IA3 - LEAST(IA1, IA2, IA3)) / 2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f81803393174d72ab3d884080ed1073)

**Update**

@GordonLinoff raises a good point that if it's possible that any of the IA* values could be `NULL`, you can use `COALESCE` to convert them to a valid integer (0 is probably the most appropriate assuming that the values would normally be positive) so that you don't end up with `NULL` values in the `average` column:

```
UPDATE analog
SET average = (COALESCE(IA1,0) + COALESCE(IA2,0) + COALESCE(IA3,0) - 
               LEAST(COALESCE(IA1,0), COALESCE(IA2,0), COALESCE(IA3,0))) / 2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a26eae33be2d6a94d5bec7a7da90ca2b)

Comment: @AnilKumar . . . This is a good solution.  Just one caveat:  it does not work if any of the values are `NULL`.  However, you haven't explained if that could happen and what to do in that case.  If that is an issue, you should ask a *new* question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good point. It can be worked around with `COALESCE`, I'll make an edit to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only 3 values then  you could try using a union for the 3 columns and

```
update   analog a
inner join  (
  select id,  (sum(IA) - min(IA))/2 val
  from (
    select id, IA1 IA
    from analog  union all  
    select id, IA2
    from analog  union  all 
    select id, IA3 
    from analog 
  ) t1  
  group  by id 
) t2  ON a.id = t2.id 
set a.average = t2.val
```